# grub видит старую ОС

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, grub, dual-boot

Всем хай. Есть SSD, на нем Ubuntu 18.04 и есть HDD,  на нем раньше стояла W10, потом снес винду и поставил Debian 9, после чего, снес дебиан и поставил trisquel 8( не спрашивайте почему так, я сам хз).

Проблема с следующем - при загрузки с HDD, есть 2 варианта:

1. трискуель либо убунту, а при загрузки с SSD:
2. убунту и винда(хотя ее уже давно нет)

Вопрос: как сделать, что бы мне предлагалось загрузить трискуель, при старте с SSD

P.S я понимаю, что можно грузиться с хдд и все нормально, но знание того, что у меня где то, что то не так, не дает мне покоя...

Comment: видимо при установке груб обновил только в одном месте.

Comment: У меня есть схожая проблема, только наоборот, был `Windows` теперь `Ubuntu`. У меня оба диска называются одинаково. ) ОС разные установлены. Хоть `SSD` разных производителей. `SATA` порты менял, ради проверки и ничего, проблема продолжается. Только у меня еще до `Grub`, при нажатии на `F11` вся эта каша, а потом уже сам `Grub`. Вроде все работает, но все в непонятках